# Battlestar Galactica Communications

Tags: battlestar-galactica, communication, battlestar-galactica-2004

Do they have audio-visual communications in the 2004 series like they showed in the 1978 series? I know in the Galactica's CIC it shows them using old phone handsets that are hard wired. Did the technology of the Colonies ever do a two way visual communication like on other scifi tv series like Star Trek, the commlock in Space: 1999. Do they have the equivalent of our cell phones?

Comment: Networks and how they came to fear them

Comment: They certainly had the *technology* but I don't recall ever seeing a person-to-person screen being used *on screen* during the show. Maybe *Caprica*?

Comment: I have never watched Caprica so it is possible to be on that show.

Comment: Naib I was also thinking of networks and thought of the hacking by the Cylons.

Comment: They had screens in Caprica. Even some sorts of virtual reality in which you could communicate "personally" with other people.